# Asp.Net Gridview.RowEditing

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm trying to design a site. I added a full one to the admin panel, so deleting a gridview insert editing operations I'm building. I have to do with encoding them for homework. When I click on the Edit button and fill in the fields to the first row in order to update, but the second row comes empty. in the same way 3. row of four. comes empty rows. so I'd say always comes empty couples. What can I do about it –

Comment: include your relevant code?

Comment: protected void gridMakale_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
        {
            gridMakale.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
            Doldur();
        }

Comment: Please post more code, it's not possible to tell what's wrong from a single line. Also please edit your question rather than posting code in a comment

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at examples of following link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowediting%28v=vs.110%29.aspx